# I cant seem to manipulate (data conversions or any other form of manipulation) csv data within a reactive() or renderDataTable()

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

am a bit new to R. I am able to manipulate csv data in any way with in  rstudio console.However,when i move the code to shinyr or shinydashboard environment, i am unable to manipulate the data apart from just reading it.
Some of the errors am getting include:

```
Warning: Error in datatable: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)
Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I have tried moving the data from renderDataTable() to reactive() since there are a lot of variables with in the code whose values change quite often based on the different csv files read.I was hoping that the data conversions such as( tostring, as.date) would be able to convert well within the reactive()

```
function(input, output, session) {
  dhh  <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    datatables <- read.csv(input$file[[1, 'datapath']], check.names=FALSE)
    return(datatables)
  })

  output$terry <- renderDataTable({
    if (is.null(dhh)) return(NULL)
    datatables <- data.frame(dhh())
    datatables
  })

  mk <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    inFile <- input$file
    datatable <- read.csv(input$file[[2, 'datapath']], check.names=FALSE)
    return(datatable) 
  })


  output$contents <- renderDataTable({
    if (is.null(mk)) return(NULL)
    datatable <- data.frame(mk())
    datatable
  })

  gloria <- reactive({
    alice <- dhh()
    calvin <- mk()
    x1=calvin[order(nrow(calvin):1),] #invert row order
    ppp <- as.character(alice$Client )
    non <- data.frame(calvin$CLIENTID)
    vcv <- c(ppp)  
    tttt <- as.vector(non)

    r <- calvin[non %in% vcv, ] 

    pipo <- r %>% 
      mutate(UPDATED.ON=as.Date(r$UPDATED.ON, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))%>% 
      group_by(CLIENTID) %>%  
      arrange(desc(UPDATED.ON)) %>%
      slice(1)

    #calculate difference in days
    y <- pipo$UPDATED.ON
    tr <- as.Date(y, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
    jp <- Sys.Date()
    ty <- as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), tr), units="days")
    ty


    })

  output$marvin <- renderDataTable({
    gloria()

  })
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please see [How to make a shiny reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable?rq=1). Meanwhile make sure _ty_ is a dataframe with at least one column and it does not a vector.

Comment: Thanks @A.Suliman, i have made ty a data frame but am now getting this error to do with date conversion       Warning: Error in mutate_impl: Evaluation error: do not know how to convert 'r$UPDATED.ON' to class <U+0093>Date<U+0094>.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230146/error-message-do-not-know-how-to-convert-dataframecol-to-class-date